# Bootstrap with own design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use Bootstrap for my site - especially for my admin backend. I would like to ask some questions before I start.

How can I understand what Bootstrap is? Is this something like a collection of tools for Webdesign or is it only an UI for every html page? Do I need a special HTML structure or Can I use it on my own HTML structure?

I would be very happy for some good tutorials and tips and maybe examples.

Comment: SO is not a good place for general advice like this, you need to ask specific questions. Please see the FAQ for the kinds of questions that are appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap is a library which helps to make your pages more fluid and responsive, it has inbuilt CSS and javascript to kick start your designing by just including the bootstrap classes,functions.

It's not a tool, you can download the source code and you can see the .css and .js files where   those classes and functions are defined.

You don't need a special HTML structure, you just need to include the bootstrap css in head tag and since twitter-bootstrap uses jQuery include the jQuery library and bootstrap jQuery file in the script tag and put into your body tag like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>...</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
 </html>
```

Start with [bootstrap getting started](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html) ...